# CSRF verification failing for post or preview using {% render_comment_form for ... %}

Tags: python, django, comments, csrf

I have `django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware` in `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` and CSRF verification is working just fine for all my other forms. `render_comment_form` is including `{% csrf_token %}` properly; I verified that the HTML is showing up. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you tell me how to use the render_comment_form tag? When I submit a form, "CSRF verification failed. Request aborted" appears. Is there a default view to work with the render_comment_form tag? Do I have to code a view? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to add

```
context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

to my render_to_response call at the end of my view. Doh!